# How to convert System.Byte[] to Image

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Hi i have the following code in which the data variable have been filled with array of bytes from databse now when i want to convert these stored bytes in the db into the image and want to show them in the picture box it gives an error at

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

And the error is **Parameter is not valid.** What should i do following is my code:

```
byte[] data = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][7];
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
ms.Position = 0;
//Image img= Image.FromStream(ms);

pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: you checked in the debugger that the data gets correct copied?

Comment: yeh!! in the debug mode i have seen that the data have something like {byte[26]} and in each element e.g [0] has the value 83 similarly [1] has 0 ,,, [2] has 121 etc upto [25]

Comment: check your image before storing in the database as byte that it is the correct image in the memory as bytes.. use the method and link that i have specified in the answer..

Comment: Once you create the MemoryStream passing data there's no need to call Write. Also, setting position is not the way to rewind the stream, you should be using Seek

Comment: Can you make the mentioned changes to my code.........i.e of seek

Comment: @MohammadAzeemAhmad - 26 bytes for an image seems rather small. Are you sure it's an image and not a string stored as bytes?

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine ; may be Image that you are saving is not in correct format. 
this may be also helpful:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx

Besides, try to set `CanWrite` property to True:

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data,true);

**EDIT:**
 As you have asked : the data type should be `Image` and i would suggest to use PNG format always rather than  GIF.

Comment: I have used the OLE Object as a Data Type to store the images in the Access DB whether this is the problem that the result is not returning correctly did i need to change that datatype????